# Create matrix with digital random numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, random

How can I create in Matlab a matrix (20 X 12) with random distribution of numbers 1 and 0, when in each column I must have 40% of numbers 1 and 60% of numbers 0? this must be random distribution.

Anyone could help me?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An efficient method is:

1. Generate matrix of uniform random values between 0 and 1.
2. For each column compute the 40-[percentile](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile).
3. For each column, set to 1 the entries that are lower or equal than the computed percentile, and set to 0 the remaining entries. This assures the desired fraction of values per column.

This can be done easily with [`prctile`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/stats/prctile.html) and [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
rows = 20;
cols = 12;
p = 40; %// percent of 1 values

A = rand(rows,cols); %// uniform random values between 0 and 1
perc = prctile(A,p); %// percentile of each column
A = bsxfun(@le, A, perc); %// 1 if lower or equal than percentile, 0 otherwise
```

Comment: perfect..this function is new for me..i will check out in help.  thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a robust method, set the first 40% of each column to be `1` and then just randomly reorder each column.

```
m=20;
n=12;
M = zeros(m,n);
M(1:round(m*0.4),:) = 1;

for col = 1:n
    M(:,col) = M(randperm(m), col);
end
```

Comment: thanks Dan. i was also using the same approach but was not getting correct output .finally found my mistake from ur reply.

Answer (score 0):

This could be one "aggressive" approach -

```
N = 10000;%%// A big number to choose 12 columns from
A = round(rand(20,N));
out = A(:,find(sum(A,1)==round(0.4*size(A,1)),12))
```

Let us know if this works for you!

Comment: thanks. it worked but what is the purpose of having large value of N? i didnt understand its use !!

Comment: Basically we are creating a large matrix (20xN) and from that choosing the first 12 columns that satisfy the criteria of 40% ones. Pretty easy to understand and use, if you ask me :)

Comment: yes i got..you are actually selecting 12 columns satisfying given condition.having limited N say 30 wouldn't make it sure that required number of entries will be obtained..

Comment: Exactly, that's why "aggressive".